# 0,1,2,....,a(b+1)までの組み合わせの表示の仕方を教えてほしいです

Tags: python

pythonにて
S=0,1,2,....,a(b+1)までの組み合わせで、このSから2つ取り出して列挙していきたいんですが、やり方がわかりません。分かるかたがいらっしゃったら、教えてほしいです。
a=4
b=2で数値を入れたいです。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
import itertools

a = 4
b = 2
c = a*(b+1)+1
l = list(itertools.combinations(range(0, c, 1), 2))
print(l)
```